# How to correctly use size_t and other integer types together?

Tags: c, types, type-conversion, size-t

For a typical loop in C, one may write:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
```

However, some people recommend using `size_t` instead:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}
```

because `unsigned int` may fail when index grows over `UINT_MAX`.

---

While I understand this, sometimes I need to use `size_t` together with other fixed-length types such as `uint32_t`, or write a number of `size_t` to network. These operations are error-prone if not handled properly. I think the same also applies to other integer types such as `ssize_t`, `socklen_t`, etc.

What is the right way to handle a mix of these different integer and size types and convert them safely when necessary?

EDIT. Another issue about the length of types is to print its value in a `printf` statement. `size_t` has its own format specifier `z`. Not all integral types have this luxury. It may be easier if `printf` accepts a `typeof` operator on the variable but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: this is of great help: -Wconversion (Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value)

Comment: See [Standard 7.20.1.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1): *[exact-width integer types are optional]*. For (extreme) portability do not rely on them.

Comment: @pmg I guess sometimes we don't have a say on not to use them: `man htons`

Comment: @Cyker `htons()` is not described in the C Standard: it is outside *extreme* portability.

Comment: @pmg I see. But then all networking routines using `htons` fall outside `extreme portability` and I bet there are important ones among them. So the above problem remains to be a practical issue of importance.

Comment: @terencehill I turned on `-Wconversion` and fixed some unsafe conversions with its help. However one remaining conversion confused me which tries to convert from `std::streamsize` to `unsigned int`. I use an `unsigned int` as the type of a variable called `length` which should be proper since a length cannot be negative and an `unsigned int` is at least 16 bits in size, which is enough for its use case. However `std::streamsize` is mapped to `long int` on my machine. Cannot understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the range of your target/source integer type to the range of the size type. The numbers should automatically promote to a large enough type for the comparison (assuming no negative numbers involved).

The maximum value of `size_t` is defined in `stdint.h` (since C99): `SIZE_MAX`. The limits of fixed width integer types are also to be found in that header, e.g., `UINT64_MAX`.

The ranges of the integer types are defined in `limits.h`: e.g., `ULONG_MAX`.

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits

Comment: +1 for the limits page. It'd better if it also covers types defined by commonly-used libraries, but they're not cpp reference, well.

Answer (score 0):

A summary of the rules are here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/types

In summary, the fixed length types are the only ones whos size can and should be relied upon. There are relative restrictions between types (such as a long is never shorter than an int), and integral types have a mandated *minumum* length (such as an int being guaranteed to be at least 16 bits).

So for network comms, you'll want either fixed length types (in network byte order for transmission and reception) or an encoding protocol (e.g. google protocol buffers).

Comment: I disagree with your summary. You can rely on the sizes of builtin types. In particular, an `int` is guaranteed to have a range of at least -32767 to 32767.

Comment: in which case my wording was sloppy. I'll fix it.

Comment: @FUZxxl I think I got out of bed the wrong side this morning. I read this question as a c++ question. Thanks for fixing up the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the right way to handle a mix of these different integer and size types and convert them safely when necessary?

Yes this is challenging and broad.
Below are some axioms that help yet are far from complete.  Some have limitations:

1. Uses `size_t` for array `[]` indexes.  (If code knows the index range is small, can use smaller types.)
2. Watch out for going below zero with `size_t`

   ```
   size_t i,a,b;
   // for (i = a; i-1 < b; i++) { // `i-1` may wrap
   for (i = a; i < b + 1; i++) { // `b+1u` may wrap but far less likely.
   ```
3. When the two types are of the same sign-ness OR the signed type is known to be wider than the unsigned one, simply code without using a cast

   ```
   if (sg <  un)
   ```
4. Otherwise handle potential negative values separately

   ```
   if (sg < 0 || sg < un)
   ```
5. To typically convert safely, test range:

   ```
   // typea --> typeb
   if (vara < typeb_MIN || vara > typeb_MAX) Handle_Error()
   else varb = vara;
   ```
6. Avoid casting `typea` to `typeb` unless code *must* convert to `typeb`.  Instead multiply by `((typeb)1)`.  This will prevent truncation (also see previous)

   ```
   (typeb) vara // avoid
   ((typeb) 1) * vara
   ```
7. When printing and code is just not clear on the range/width of a type, use a max width type

   ```
   ssize_t ssz = foo();
   printf("%jd\n", ((intmax_t)1) * ssz);
   printf("%lld\n", 1LL * ssz);
   ```
8. When calculating the byte size of a 2D array, multiply by the `size_t` type first

   ```
   p = malloc(width * height * sizeof *p);   // potential overflow in width * height
   p = malloc(sizeof *p * width * height);
   ```

---

Note: Some C integer types

- Signed: `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long` `long long` `intmax_t`
- Unsigned: `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned`, `unsigned long` `unsigned long long` `uintmax_t`
- Also `char` is either signed or unsigned.
- Special: (unsigned) `size_t`  (signed) `ptrdiff_t`
- Exact-width (optional) examples: `int8_t`, `uint32_t` and maybe surprising ones `uint24_t`.
- Minimum-width (at least 8 types) `int_least8_t`, ..., `uint_least64_t`.
- Fast-width (at least 8 types) `int_fast8_t`, ..., `uint_fast64_t`.
- Also `wchar_t`, `wint_t`, `sig_atomic_t`, `max_align_t`, ..., ... , ... etc.
- Bit-fields.

Many of these types are simply `typedef`s of others.  Others like `int` and `long` may have the same range but maintain their distinctive type-ness.